# [NextJS]`yarn dev` command throwing error: Assertion `args[0]->IsInt32()' failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

While running `yarn dev` for NextJS local development, I am getting this error output:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node[8717]: ../src/tcp_wrap.cc:155:static  void node::TCPWrap::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[0]->IsInt32()' failed.
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
51: 0x1044f3d70 node::crypto::TLSWrap::Cycle() [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
52: 0x1044f229c node::crypto::TLSWrap::OnStreamRead(long, uv_buf_t const&) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
53: 0x10448a48c node::LibuvStreamWrap::OnUvRead(long, uv_buf_t const*) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
54: 0x10448a13c node::LibuvStreamWrap::ReadStart()::$_1::__invoke(uv_stream_s*, long, uv_buf_t const*) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
55: 0x106d32ff0 uv__stream_io [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libuv/1.44.2/lib/libuv.1.dylib]
56: 0x106d3a1e0 uv__io_poll [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libuv/1.44.2/lib/libuv.1.dylib]
57: 0x106d2a7bc uv_run [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libuv/1.44.2/lib/libuv.1.dylib]
58: 0x1042fd8d8 node::SpinEventLoopInternal(node::Environment*) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
59: 0x1044025c0 node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::ExitCode*, node::Environment*) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
60: 0x104402344 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
61: 0x10438acf4 node::LoadSnapshotDataAndRun(node::SnapshotData const**, node::InitializationResultImpl const*) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
62: 0x10438ae90 node::Start(int, char**) [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.9.0/bin/node]
63: 0x18640fe50 start [/usr/lib/dyld]
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
```

Things tried:

1.
`yarn install`
`yarn cache clean`
multiple times.

2. carefully revised package.json as well.
3. tried downgrading node version to 14 and 16.
4. restored to previous working branch.

Situation:
5.
`yarn build`
generated output is working fine on deploy, hence the issue is related to dev-related packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to solve this. But I've found a workaround by doing:

```
yarn build && yarn start
```